# Subtract last year's ending quarter value from current quarter value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I know

```
(DateAdd("s",-1,
DateAdd("q",DateDiff("q","1/1/1900",
DateAdd("yyyy",-1,Date())),"1/1/1900")),
"Short Date")
```

returns the last day of a quarter 1 year ago.

All of the NAV_Dates are the last day of each quarter, and have a value associated with them which makes the row unique. (Closing value titled as NetAssetValue)

How can I use that (or something similar), to get the value associated with the ending year quarterly date, and subtract it from the value of the current quarter's ending value. Note: I do not have to use this, it's just the only SQL I know that will return a value to somewhat close to what I need.

The table's values would be set up similar to this:

```
+----------+--------------+
|NAV_Date  |NetAssetValue |
+----------+--------------+
|12/31/2012|        $4,000|
+----------+--------------+
|03/31/2013|        $5,000|
+----------+--------------+
```

The Year to Date would then be (5,000/4,000) - 1 and saved as a percent. Another example would be:

```
+----------+--------------+
|NAV_Date  |NetAssetValue |
+----------+--------------+
|12/31/2012|        $4,000|
+----------+--------------+
|06/30/2013|        $4,025|
+----------+--------------+
```

Year to Date calculation: (4,025/4,000) - 1 and saved as a percent.

I know it involves a nested subquery (or possibly more than one) and that we'd essentially have to capture the current quarter's end, use that value, and capture the prior year's quarter end and use that value also. Just not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track considering a correlated subquery for this.  I think you want the subquery to return the year-end `NetAssetValue` for each quarterly record.

I hope the `WHERE` clause in this query makes the logic clear.  However it would force the subquery to run the `Year()` function against every row in the table.  Even so, you may be satisfied with the performance if the table is small enough.

```sql
SELECT
    y1.NAV_Date,
    y1.NetAssetValue,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 y2.NetAssetValue
        FROM YourTable AS y2
        WHERE Year(y2.NAV_Date) = Year(y1.NAV_Date)
        ORDER BY y2.NAV_Date DESC
    ) AS YearEndValue
FROM YourTable AS y1;
```

I think the following `WHERE` clause should offer better performance than the one above, assuming `NAV_Date` is indexed.  However, you may find it less intuitive.  If so, try the first version and then work on this one later if you need it:

```sql
    WHERE y2.NAV_Date <= DateSerial(Year(y1.NAV_Date), 12, 31)
```

Beware, in the current year, the query will return `NetAssetValue` from the most recent quarterly record as `YearEndValue`, even though the year hasn't ended.  I don't know what else you would want in that situation.

Finally, the query should give you `NetAssetValue` and `YearEndValue` for each quarter.  All you have left is to add your calculation which uses those values.

Comment: Your SQL retrieves the current `YearEndValue` and for my calculation I need the **previous** year's ending quarterly value. As is, I am dividing the current `NetAssetValue` by the current year's ending NAV, where I actually need the **prior year's ending value**. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I just added  -1 after `Year(y1.NAV_Date)`